Unknown logs in registered persisted query
I am trying to implement registered persisted query. when i am running a query which is not there in my PQL, with apq as enabled it is logging the query in router logs with error code “PersistedQueryNotFound”
persisted_queries:
  enabled: true
  log_unknown: true
apq:
  enabled: true

but when i disable apq and run the query it is not getting logged in router logs. It is giving me status code - 404 with error code “PERSISTED_QUERY_NOT_IN_LIST”.
persisted_queries:
  enabled: true
  log_unknown: true
apq:
  enabled: false # APQ must be turned off

Has anyone else faced this or is there anyway i can get the logs when apq is disabled.
Router version - 1.53.0
Thanks in advance
I tried with various configs and i expect logs coming up for unknown queries even if apq is off. telemetry logs of those will also work.
